# Android include layout

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<include layout="@layout/basicinfo" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="profile" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="item" />

</LinearLayout >
```

the problem is that it only shows the include part,no buttons showing up. if I remove the include layout, buttons will show up. any idea what I am doing wrong here? thanks.

**update: the basicinfo layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Name:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Catogery:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Owner" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you also post the included layout xml?

Comment: Could you post your basicinfo xml file too?

Comment: haa...I thought it d be too much to post. I will update it anyway.

Comment: This problem has been solved. see my own answer. I can not accept it within two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fount out the problem. it was because I used match_parent in basic layout. I just changed that from

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

Define your include file layout_height and width for eample:

```
<include layout="@layout/basicinfo"     
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work. but using a fixed dimension may not be good across devices.

Comment: Yes. you are right. but suppose yous basicinfo file has a large number of content in that case some of you main layout's content will be missing. So another solution is to use layout_weight

Answer (score 1):

I would check layout_width and layout_height. This is mostly the point in displaying errors.

Answer (score 1):

included layout is as big as the screen dimension, so the buttons are outside view area. you need to give dimension to this include layout

Comment: I try the layoutwidth and height with wrap-content. it did not seem to work.

Comment: try to put exact values...200 dip for example.

Comment: i saw that you still have match parent at linearLayout from your include xml...try to change that..in wrap_content...or put some values such as 150dip or something else

Answer (score 0):

Change the outer LinearLayout width and height to fill_parent and also place a scroll bar inside it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main issues with an include layout is that BOTH `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` must be included or the layout will simply fill the screen (if for instance only the height is set, it will be ignored without setting the width as well).

So something like this should be done:

```
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/myLayout" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Merge...

use the  element as the root view for the re-usable layout

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <Button
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/add"/>

  <Button
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/delete"/>

</merge>
```

[Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)